# How to fix "UnsupportedCommandException: actions" error with Android automation

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I'm trying to run a command to scroll a screen on an emulator.  I had tried a set of action commands from the Action class, but they were inconsistent.  I eventually stumbled upon the code below.

Is there something I need to import or include to make these actions function correctly?  My other confusion is that this code works while using the Espresso driver, but produces this error message when running under the UiAutomator2 driver.  I have tried importing the Action class, but this does not fix the issue.  Again, is there something that needs to be imported or used specifically for these commands on the UiAutomator2 driver?

This code works while using the Espresso driver, but produces this error message when running under the UiAutomator2 driver.  I have tried importing the Action class, but this does not fix the issue.

```
WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(originLocator));
WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(destinationLocator));

int startY = element1.getLocation().getY() + (element1.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
int startX = element1.getLocation().getX() + (element1.getSize().getWidth() / 2);

int endX = element2.getLocation().getX() + (element2.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
int endY = element2.getLocation().getY() + (element2.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

PointerInput input = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "input");
Sequence swipeTo = new Sequence(input, 0);
swipeTo.addAction(input.createPointerMove(Duration.ZERO, PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), startX, startY)); 
swipeTo.addAction(input.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
swipeTo.addAction(input.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(1000), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), endX, endY));
swipeTo.addAction(input.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
driver.perform(Arrays.asList(swipeTo));
```

This should scroll the visible page of the mobile app on the emulator, but currently it causes the following error (`org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: actions`) when run with the UiAutomator2 driver.

Edit: After applying the code from a comment below I have the following code which works with the UiAutomator2 driver consistently, but not with the Espresso driver (it targets the wrong space on-screen and seems to tap an element instead of touch and hold).

```
    WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(originLocator));
    WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(destinationLocator));

    int startY = element1.getLocation().getY() + (element1.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
    int startX = element1.getLocation().getX() + (element1.getSize().getWidth() / 2);

    int endX = element2.getLocation().getX() + (element2.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
    int endY = element2.getLocation().getY() + (element2.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

    Dimension dim=driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int height=(int) dim.getHeight();
    int width=(int) dim.getWidth();
    int x= width/2;
    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(PointOption.point(x,startY))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(x,endY))
            .release()
            .perform();
```

So I do have a working version for each driver.  Does anyone know why these have differing behaviors depending on the driver in use?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scroll on android app you can use touch action class. Below code will scroll down. If you want to scroll up change startY and startX accordingly. Hope it helps.

```
public void scrollDown() {
    Dimension dim=new Dimension();
    int height=(int) dim.getHeight();
    int width=(int) dim.getWidth();
    int x= width/2;
    int startY=(int) (height*0.80);
    int endY=(int) (height*0.20);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(x, startY).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).moveTo(x, endY).release().perform();   
}
```

Comment: So I worked in your example and got a version that works with UiAutomator2, but not Espresso.  I'm posting the new code in an edit above.  Do you have any idea why the code I showed originally isn't accepted by UiAutomator2 and throws that error message, but works fine with the Espresso driver?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AndroidDriver driver and there is a method for swipe supported in the AppiumDriver class so you dont need to use Action class to swipe the page.
I have made a generic parametrised method to swipe vertically up and down which swipes according to the swipe type.
The code is as follows:

```
public enum SwipeType {
    VerticallyUp, VerticallyDown
}

public void swipeVertically(int swipeValue, SwipeType Move) {
Double swipeHeight = 0.0;
swipeHeight = (double) swipeValue;
Dimension screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Double screenWidth = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(screenSize.getWidth())) / 2;
Double screenHeight = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(screenSize.getHeight())) / 2;

    if (screenHeight + swipeValue > screenHeight * 2 || swipeValue == 0) {
    swipeHeight = screenHeight / 2;
    }
    switch (Move) {
    case VerticallyUp:

    driver.swipe(screenWidth.intValue(), screenHeight.intValue() + swipeHeight.intValue(), screenWidth.intValue(), screenHeight.intValue(), 2000);
    break;

    case VerticallyDown:
    driver.swipe(screenWidth.intValue(), screenHeight.intValue(), screenWidth.intValue(), screenHeight.intValue() + swipeHeight.intValue(), 2000);
    break;
    }
}
```

I have used swipeValue as 300 as it works perfectly for my app. You can use it according to your app.
I hope this helps!!